# uwsgi always binds to 80 port. Even when configured not to

Tags: sockets, binding, port, uwsgi

I'm trying to start uwsgi listening on custom 8008 port. As mentioned in [security section of uwsgi docs](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#security-and-availability) I used `uid` and `gid` params to make it from `www-data` user

```
uwsgi --http-socket :8008 --uid=www-data --gid=www-data
```

But I continuously get an error

```
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 769]
```

After straceing this problem I figured out that uwsgi tries to bind to 80 port even when I choose another one.

After many attempts it seems that it **allways** binds to 80 port. Along with the port I choosed.

For example (running as root)
output of

```
uwsgi --http-socket :8008
```

contains

```
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :80 fd 3
uwsgi socket 1 bound to TCP address :8008 fd 4
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
```

another example with environment variable configuration:

```
UWSGI_SOCKET=:8009 uwsgi --http-socket :8008
```

produces

```
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :8009 fd 3
uwsgi socket 1 bound to TCP address :80 fd 4
uwsgi socket 2 bound to TCP address :8008 fd 5
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
```

- No matter how to configure it: via cli-params, .yml-file or
  environment variables.
- No matter what parameter to choose `http-socket` or `http` or just `socket`
- No matter how to point to that port: `0.0.0.0:8008` or just `:8008` (or even UNIX socket)

It always tries to bind to 80-th port and reasonably fails if doing it from not-root user

Doing all that stuff under Ubuntu 17.10 in docker with uwsgi 2.0.17.1
Trying to install uwsgi from debian packages and from python pip3 - same behaviour.

Any ideas of what I'm missing? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out what is going on.
I had wrong configuration in my docker-compose.yml file.

```
environment:
  UWSGI_HTTP_SOCKET: :80
```

That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:80 --uid=www-data --gid=www-data
```

Comment: Last three lines of output: 
uWSGI http bound on 127.0.0.1:8008 fd 3
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 15)
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 769]

Comment: Right now I mentioned that it fails trying to bind to 80 port but in background there is some uwsgi process binded to 8008. Looks like there is some instruction to always listen an extra 80 port. And I have no idea how to ask it to forget that port.

Comment: Right. I'll set 80 port in the answer. So, if you kill every process running of uwsgi, and then run only the command: `uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:80 --uid=www-data --gid=www-data`, what kind of output gives you the `netstat -tulpn` command?

Comment: Ok. I've missed that and have tried to run  with 8008. Sorry for misunderstanding. Now I run the same clean container, run your command with 80 port and got 18 lines of output with the las one `bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 769]`. After that I ran  `netstat -tulpn` as you asked and saw no processes listens thhis port. Actually no uwsgi is running because it fails. (This comment is not convenient place to paste whole output)

Comment: But I'm not surprised that it falls when trying to bind 80 under unprivileged user. That's ok. My problem is how to ask uwsgi not to listen on 80 port at all.